# PHP/javascript? allow only two submissions within 10 min?

Tags: php, javascript, html, contacts, submission

http://www.3dmark3t.com/contact.html[1](http://www.3dmark3t.com/contact.html) Here is my contact form I want to be able to only allow 2 submissions from 1 ip address within 10 min. Please help me with this?
Here is my php script for the form validation:

```
                <?php
            if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

                // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
                $email_to = "email@domain.com";

                $email_subject = "3DMark3t Contact:";


                function died($error) {
                    // your error code can go here
                    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
                    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
                    echo $error."<br /><br />";
                    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
                    die();
                }

                // validation expected data exists
               if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
                !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
                !isset($_POST['email']) ||
                !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
                !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
              if(empty($_POST['select']) )
            {
              $var3dmodels = $_POST['3DModels'];
              $vargraphic_design = $_POST['Graphic Design'];
              $varweb_design = $_POST['Web Design'];
              $vartutorials = $_POST['Tutorials'];
              $varreport = $_POST['Report'];
              $varrequests = $_POST['Requests'];
            }
                    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
                }




                $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
                $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
                $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
                $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
                $select = $_POST['select']; // required
                $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

                $error_message = "";
                $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
              if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
                $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
              }
                $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
              if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
                $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
              }
              if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
                $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
              }
            if(empty($_POST['select']))
            {
              $error_message .= 'The Selection you made does not appear to be valid.<br />';
            }
              if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
                $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
              }
              if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
                died($error_message);
              }
                $email_message = '3DMark3t Contact:';

                function clean_string($string) {
                  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
                }

                $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Select One: ".clean_string($select)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


            // create email headers
            $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
            ?>

            <!-- place your own success html below -->

            <img src="../images/loading-circle.gif" width="32" height="32" />  Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
            <script type = "text/javascript">setTimeout('window.opener.location.href=\'http://www.3dmark3t.com\';close();', 3000)</script>
            <?php
            }
            die();
            ?>
```

Comment: You'd need to do that in PHP, and since it's hopefully not possible to view your PHP source, you'd need to post some PHP code as to what you've tried.

Comment: I'd use a captcha.  Often companies use NAT and share an IP, so you would be blocking access (to the rest of that company) when one user submits twice.

Comment: @James I have tried to get captcha to work on my fom but I can never get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a user can destroy their session within two minutes and submit again, this has to be done on your end (probably with a DB).  Your DB should keep track of user submissions and IP addresses.  When a user submits (or visits the submission form), check their IP against your DB.  If they've made a submission in the last 2 (or is it 10) minutes, show an error and refuse them.  If you need some code, I need to see what code you're working with.

Comment: Okay I posted the code, now I know that some company's share ip addresses how would I can I just get it to where if one user submits twice within two min only that user can't submit within another untill 10 min are over?

Comment: If you're not using a DB, you have to use the session.  Do you not have a DB available?

Comment: Whats DB? DataBase? obviously if I'm asking you I don't have it lol

Comment: Yeah right now i don't have that. I their any possible way I can do it wihtout mySQL?

Comment: You can write to a file (and use that as your DB) but that's not very dependable.  If you limit them to one submission per session, (you can just set something in `_SESSION` and check that it's not set) it'll work, but if they clear their cookies in less than two minutes they'll get to make submission.

Answer (score 1):

Checking using IP addresses is fatally flawed - as some companies (even ISPs) share IP addresses. There is no solution that guarentees but why not explore using cookies instead (along with something like Captcha)